# Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ find $x\in (0,1)$ such that $p(n,x)<10^{-12}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ find $x\in (0,1)$ such that $p(n,x)<10^{-12}$, if:
>   $$p(n,x)=x(1-x)\frac{x^{n-2}}{1-x^2}+x(1-x)\frac{(1-x)^{n-2}}{1-(1-x)^2}.$$

*Attempt*. We may also write

$$p(n,x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x}+\frac{(1-x)^{n-1}}{2-x},$$

but it seems hard to solve

$$\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x}+\frac{(1-x)^{n-1}}{2-x}<10^{-12}$$

in terms of $x=x(n)$. Is there a way to reach a concrete form, or at least, some information on the desired $x$?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Major changes ! We have now almost the analytical solution. Thansk for the problem. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x}+\frac{(1-x)^{n-1}}{2-x}$$ and notice the symmetry around $x=\frac 12$.

So, let $x=y+\frac 12$ and consider the function
$$g(y)=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-y\right)^{n-1}}{\frac{3}{2}-y}+\frac{\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{y+\frac{3}{2}}$$ where $0 \leq y \leq \frac 12$. This function is still not very well conditioned but, for given $n$, its logarithm is much better, looking like a $\large V$ shape curve.

Since I do not see any way to avoid numerical method, we need an estimate of the variable and, instead of solving $f(x)=10^{-k}$, we shall try to find the zero of function
$$h(y)=\log\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-y\right)^{n-1}}{\frac{3}{2}-y}+\frac{\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{y+\frac{3}{2}} \right)+k\log(10)$$

Expanding $\log(g(y))$ as an infinite series built at $y=\frac 12$, we have
$$\log(g(y))=-\log (2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{ \left(2^{-k}-n+1\right) }{k}\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$$

Now, using series reversion
$$y=\frac{1}{2}+t+\frac{(4 n-5) t^2}{4 (2 n-3)}+\frac{\left(16 n^2-36 n+21\right)
   t^3}{24 (2 n-3)^2}+\frac{\left(64 n^3-200 n^2+228 n-93\right) t^4}{192 (2
   n-3)^3}+\frac{\left(256 n^4-1056 n^3+1896 n^2-1596 n+501\right) t^5}{1920 (2
   n-3)^4}+\frac{\left(1024 n^5-5504 n^4+13344 n^3-15264 n^2+7884 n-1485\right)
   t^6}{23040 (2 n-3)^5}+O\left(t^{7}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{2 (\log (2)-k \log (10))}{2 n-3}$

Trying for $k=12$ as requested, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 50  & 0.074283757193 &  0.074280567685 \\
 60  & 0.131266692251 &  0.131265832666 \\
 70  & 0.175046836738 &  0.175046551370 \\
 80  & 0.209658736187 &  0.209658626086 \\
 90  & 0.237674620683 &  0.237674573066 \\
 100 & 0.260798780945 &  0.260798758418 \\
 110 & 0.280200353757 &  0.280200342301 \\
 120 & 0.296706076798 &  0.296706070614 \\
 130 & 0.310916165380 &  0.310916161870 \\
 140 & 0.323276469382 &  0.323276467305 \\
 150 & 0.334124864087 &  0.334124862811 \\
 160 & 0.343721940253 &  0.343721939444 \\
 170 & 0.352271831379 &  0.352271830852 \\
 180 & 0.359936672989 &  0.359936672637 \\
 190 & 0.366846847576 &  0.366846847336 \\
 200 & 0.373108377667 &  0.373108377500 \\
 210 & 0.378808349784 &  0.378808349665 \\
 220 & 0.384018953814 &  0.384018953728 \\
 230 & 0.388800532501 &  0.388800532438 \\
 240 & 0.393203912475 &  0.393203912428 \\
 250 & 0.397272206517 &  0.397272206483
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you want a more compact form to replace the series expansion, you could use

$$y=1+t+t^2 \left(\frac {a_0+a_1 t}{1+a_2 t}\right)$$
$$a_0=\frac{4 n-5}{4 (2 n-3)}\qquad  a_1=\frac{256 n^4-1248 n^3+2136 n^2-1512 n+369}{96 (2 n-3)^2 \left(16 n^2-36
   n+21\right)}$$
$$a_2=\frac{-64 n^3+200 n^2-228 n+93}{8 (2 n-3) \left(16 n^2-36 n+21\right)}$$

**Warning**

You must take care that the solution exists only if

$$k \log (10)+\log \left(\frac{2^{3-n}}{3}\right) < 0$$

Comment: In our case, $n$ is constant and we are looking for all $x\in (0,1)$ s.t. $p(n,x)<10^{-k}$. We are not looking for $n$ s.t. $p(n,x)<10^{-k}$ for all $x$ (i believe your responce was for the last case).

Comment: @NikolaosSkout.  Sorry ! I misunderstood. I shall work the other case (or try)

Comment: Very nice, working with the $y$ problem. One thing of course is that we want to solve the inequality (not (just) find the zeros).

Comment: @NikolaosSkout. You simply need that $y$ be smaller than the solution.